# How do I resolve the ClassCastException while retrieving an array of objects from a .txt file?

Tags: java

I have created an array of objects of type Employee and i am putting the objects in a .txt file.
Below is the method that accepts Employee objects a parameter and puts it into the .txt file

```
public void putDataintoFile(Employee[] obj) {
    File file = new File("employeedetails.txt");
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EmployeeService1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EmployeeService1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

This above method is invoked from a seperate "Execetor class " which then calls my getDataFromFile() method below

```
public void getDataFromFile() {
    System.out.println("Reached HERE");
    try {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("employeedetails.txt");
        try {
            ObjectInputStream oin= new ObjectInputStream(fin);
            try {
                Employee    e =(Employee)oin.readObject();
                System.out.println("Reached HERE");
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EmployeeService1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            oin.close();
            fin.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EmployeeService1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EmployeeService1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

On executign I get an error which says.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [LMypackage.Employee; cannot
be cast to Mypackage.Employee
at Mypackage.EmployeeService1.getDataFromFile(EmployeeService1.java:225)
at Mypackage.Executor.main(Executor.java:71)
```

I have implemented Serializable interface in my Employee Classs

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're writing an array and trying to read a single object.

This is stated in the exception message, which leads to the read/write code, which is fairly obvious despite all the superfluous vertical whitespace.

Also, in general, don't call not-text files `.txt`.

Comment: `code`
Employee e[] = new Employee[2];
                   for(int i=0 ;i<2;i++)
                   {
                       e[i] =(Employee)oin.readObject();
                     System.out.println(e[i]);
                   
                   }
`code`
I tried this but still the same error

Comment: its working I was not entering the objects into the file  using a loop

 I changed my `code` putData() tofor(int i=0 ;i<2;i++)
                {
                oos.writeObject(obj[i]);
                }
                oos.close();
                fos.close();
`code`
and my getData method to
`code`
Employee e[] = new Employee[2];
                   for(int i=0 ;i<2;i++)
                   {
                       e[i] =(Employee)oin.readObject();
                     System.out.println(e[i]);
                   
                   }
`code`